# Adding Batch GET request results to a list using Simple.Odata.Client

Tags: c#, lambda, odata

Using Simple.Odata.Client, I am batching GET requests and adding the results of those requests to a list. Like below:

```
        var results = new List<Thing>();
        var ids = new List<long>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        var batch = new ODataBatch(_client);

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            batch += async c =>
            {
                results.Add(await c.For<Thing>().Key(id).FindEntryAsync());
            };
        }

        await batch.ExecuteAsync();
```

The problem is that (as described here - https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/issues/181) the batch handler is called twice which means that for every successful result that is added to the results list, a null value is added as well.

The solution was said to be "move all statements not related to batch operations (like results.Add(...)) out of the batch lambda." However I don't understand how that can be done because I don't have access to the result of the batch request outside the lambda. I understand a solution would be to check for null before adding the result to the results list but I would like to see if anyone knows a better way, or can explain how to add the results outside of the batch lambda. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here. Because the batch handler is called twice, the only real solution I found was assigning the result of the query to a local variable in the batch lambda, and then adding that result to the results list only if the result is not null.

Here's an example:

```
        var results = new List<Thing>();
        var ids = new List<long>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        var batch = new ODataBatch(_client);

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            batch += async c =>
            {
                Thing result;
                result = await c.For<Thing>().Key(id).FindEntryAsync();

                if (result != null) {
                    results.Add(result);
                }
            };
        }

        await batch.ExecuteAsync();
```